# Let X be any random variable. Find $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to-\infty} P[X \le b]$...

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be any random variable. Find $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to-\infty} P[X \le b]$

I would think $b$ is zero, making this an infinite sum but really not sure. Any help/direction with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have $b\to -\infty$, because $X$ might be negative part of the time.

Comment: $P$ is a finite sigma-additive measure, hence for all decreasing sequences of sets $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\cdots$ it holds $$P\left(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$$

$$\lim_{b \to -\infty} F_X(b) = 0 = \lim_{b \to -\infty} P(X \leq b)$$

Comment: $-\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman I know but it is not that unusual to use this notation in this case.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman Still i hesitated...so i will remove it.